Mid 80s HBO Sci-Fi kids movie - depressed young girl who lives on Mars and misses Earth
Does anyone remember a Science Fiction kids movie series on HBO around the mid-80s that depicts the life of a depressed young girl who lives on Mars and misses Earth? She was so sad that she couldn't go outside to play. The same actress was then in another movie in the series where she was horrifyingly cloned by her parents. I think they were part of an HBO after school program, that I was fascinated with back then. I'd love to show them to my daughter.

It looks like All Summer in a Day, 1982. IMDb extract:

On the planet Venus, it rains almost constantly. A classroom full of young children are excited to hear that the rain will stop today, for just one hour. But they are also resentful of a new classmate from Earth, who remembers what it's like to see the sun.

You may also be thinking of the great short story by Ray Bradbury by the same name.



